# Consulta muy sencilla sobre JS o Vue

Tags: javascript, buenas-prácticas

Lo siguiente en si no es un problema, mas bien es que soy un desarrollador Junior y estoy aprendiendo a fondo Vue, y quiero aprenderlo de la mejor manera siguiendo pasos de gente de la gente que ya sabe.

Asi que expongo una imagen del codigo y el 'lio',
quiero hacer una pequeña app para registro, y quiero pasar entre pantallas las preguntas que quiero hacer por seccion, pero no usare modulos, ya que solo quiero mostrar unas 6 pantallas para animarlas, asi que opte por usar V-if para apagarlas u ocultarlas segun el estado en el que e encuentre el usuario.

Lo que acabo de hacer funciona, pero NECESITO SABER, si es la mejor manera de implementarlo o me recomiendan una forma mas 'SIMPLE'... 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y si intentas con alguna librería como: https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard

Comment: mmm la verdad no lo habia pensado. Pero lo voy a mirar a ver que tal. SE VE MUY BIEN!!! .. GRACIAS POR LA IDEA.

Comment: ¿Una mejor manera respecto a qué criterio? ¿Más simple para mí, más simple para tí,  más simple para un invidente, o más simple para quien? Lo más probable es que aún no tengas respuestas debido a que como habrás notado tu pregunta es basada en opiniones, es decir, subjetiva.